# What does G in ZG stands for?

Tags: equities

I see the tickers Z and ZG are for the same company, zillow. But I don't understand what G stands for. Could anybody let me know?

Answer (score 2):

The way to find answers to questions like this is to look in the 10K. For example

https://yahoo.brand.edgar-online.com/displayfilinginfo.aspx?FilingID=15552152-254326-258388&type=sect&TabIndex=2&dcn=0001617640-22-000013

> **Item 5. Market for Registrant’s Common Equity...**
>
> Our Class A common stock has traded on The Nasdaq Global
> Select Market under the symbol **“ZG”** since August 17, 2015 and under
> the symbol **“Z”** from July 20, 2011 through August 14, 2015.
>
> Our Class B
> common stock is not listed and there is no established public trading
> market.
>
> Our Class C capital stock has traded on The Nasdaq Global
> Select Market under the symbol **“Z”** since August 17, 2015. Prior to
> that time, there was no public market for our Class C capital stock.

and if you search old media releases, you find:

https://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/zillow-group-announces-stock-dividend-creation-of-class-c-shares-300116581.html

> On August 14, 2015, all shareholders of record of Zillow Group's Class
> A and Class B common stock... will receive a dividend of two shares of
> Class C capital stock for each share of Class A and Class B common
> stock held by them as of the record date.
>
> ...Application to the Nasdaq Stock Market has been made to list the Class C capital stock.  Following the issuance date of the dividend, Zillow Group expects the Class C capital stock will trade under the ticker symbol "Z" and the Class A common stock will trade under the ticker symbol "ZG".
>
> ...The Class C capital stock is a non-voting class of capital stock that shares equally with the Class A common stock and Class B common stock with respect to all economic benefits.